# ojdbc6 jar for 12c not working with mule 3.5

Tags: oracle, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, ojdbc

My old ojdbc6 jar for oracle 11g database works fine with mule 3.5 but when i replaced that jar with that of oracle 12 c, I got following error while running my mule flow : 
Exception stack is:
1. Unable to find a mapping for type ID: 0 Name: null (org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.type.UnknownDbTypeException)
  org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.type.CompositeDbTypeManager:59 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/db/internal/domain/type/UnknownDbTypeException.html)
2. Unable to find a mapping for type ID: 0 Name: null (org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.type.UnknownDbTypeException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

---

Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.type.UnknownDbTypeException: Unable to find a mapping for type ID: 0 Name: null
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.type.CompositeDbTypeManager.lookup(CompositeDbTypeManager.java:59)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.param.QueryParamTypeResolver.getParameterTypes(QueryParamTypeResolver.java:48)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.param.DefaultParamTypeResolver.getParamTypesUsingMetadata(DefaultParamTypeResolver.java:74)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.param.DefaultParamTypeResolver.getParameterTypes(DefaultParamTypeResolver.java:39)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.AbstractDbConnection.getParamTypes(AbstractDbConnection.java:53)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.query.ParametrizedQueryResolver.getParameterTypes(ParametrizedQueryResolver.java:68)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.query.ParametrizedQueryResolver.resolve(ParametrizedQueryResolver.java:56)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.executeQuery(AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.java:38)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor.process(AbstractDbMessageProcessor.java:66)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:118)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:189)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:182)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:109)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:181)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:39)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

---

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 12 you should use [ojdbc7.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html) if you're using JDK 7 or 8 and ojdbc6.jar only when using JDK 6. Please try with ojdbc7.jar.

Comment: I am using ojdbc6 jar with JDK 6 and I am getting above error.